# Recursively going through a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

So I have a dictionary;

```
dictionary = {"one": ["two"], "two": ["three"], "three": [None]}
```

How can I recursively go through in a function to find one if i am given three?
example: does one end up as three? Yes because one --> two --> three and the same back down. three --> two --> one

So far I have tried to use a list comprehension on the dictionary;

```
def function(start, end, dict_to_check):
    if dict_to_check[end] == start:
        return True
    else:
        var = {key: value for key, value in dict_to_check.items() if value == start}
        return var
```

but this does not use recursion and I have no idea how to go about

Comment: Where do you do the recursion in your program? Recursion means that something is defined in terms of itself. But here you do not call `function` inside the `function`.

Comment: I am not using recursion in my attempt so i tried using the dictionary comprhension

Comment: Can you explain why in your attempt you construct a dictionary and return that?

Comment: In your example, "one" ends up as `None`.  Do you want to identify the general case where B exists somewhere along the linked list that begins with A?  Also, why do you need to evaluate "the same back down. three --> two --> one"?

Comment: Furthermore it is not entirely clear to me what do you mean with "same back down". Does that mean that the dictionary works bidirectional? So that if it is `{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['b']}` we can move from `a` to `c`?

Comment: This is a really dangerous thing to do because you could make an infinite loop really easily. Your base case isn't guaranteed, which is a basic thing for recursion. Try looking up the traversal of a linked list. That is basically what you have here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
start = "one"
end = "three"
dictionary = {"one": ["two"], "two": ["three"], "three": [None]}
def check(s):
  if not dictionary[s][0]:
     return "Not found"
  if dictionary[s][0] == end:
     return "found"
  else:
     return check(dictionary[s][0])


print(check(start))
```

Output:

```
found
```